# How do I get the Public Feeds from our Fanpage without forcing users to accept an app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

I would like to embed our latest facebook-posts to our website.
I know the Social-Plugin Likebox, but this has not all the features I need.

This are the missing features in Like-Box, that I need:

- get the posts from our fanpage every x minutes and save it in our database
- filter the posts with keywords (because we got posts, that are to be shown only on facebook and not on our website)
- also show the posts to people that are not yet in facebook (read from our database)
- Make our own style of showing the posts on our website

This is what I have done yet

- I am the Administrator of our fanpage (of course)
- I have created an facebook app to get an appid and appsecret
- I am using the facebook php sdk to communicate with facebook
- Find out, that its not possible to get the content that I want with the AppId and the Secret key.

CODE:

```
$profileId ="XXX"    
$facebook       = new Facebook(array(
            "appId"  => "XXX",
            "secret" => "XXX",
            "cookie" => true
        ));
$curlOptions = array(
                CURLOPT_URL            => "https://graph.facebook.com/{$profileId}/posts?limit=10&access_token=" . $facebook->getAccessToken(),
                CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH       => CURLAUTH_ANYSAFE,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
            );
```

The response is empty data.

- I have Read a tons of Topics, but I am still having trouble

Why I dont get the content?

I don't need any data from our Users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are an admin on the fanpage, you can provide yourself with a page access token that has been extended indefinitely through Scenario 5 https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ and set that in the PHP SDK while saving it to the database `$facebook->setAccessToken('PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN');`

> When a user grants an app the manage_pages permission, the app is able to obtain page access tokens for pages that the user administers by querying the [User ID]/accounts Graph API endpoint. With the migration enabled, when using a short-lived user access token to query this endpoint, the page access tokens obtained are short-lived as well.
>
> Exchange the short-lived user access token for a long-lived access token using the endpoint and steps explained earlier.
>
> `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
>
>       client_id=APP_ID&
>       client_secret=APP_SECRET&
>       grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
>       fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN`
>
> By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages. This will also apply when querying with a non-expiring user access token obtained through the deprecated offline_access permission.

An example can be seen at

http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/getting-your-facebook-page-on-your-website-with-access-tokens/